# Notepad++ delete characters from a line that exceeds certain number of characters

Tags: notepad++

I have a huge txt file and since I am parsing it and the program generating it does sometimes outputs way too much text for one field, I want a way to completely delete after certain number of characters on a line, not word wrap but actually delete as after certain point it seems like it is an error of the program creating the txt and I already have a script to transform the txt into a csv, however the script has issues when a line exceeds 32767 characters.

Answer (score 3):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `^.{32767}\K.*$`
- Replace with: `LEAVE EMPTY`
- *check Wrap around*
- *check Regular expression*
- *UNCHECK `. matches newline`*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
^           # beginning of line
  .{32767}  # 32767 any character but newline
  \K        # forget all we have seen until this posiiton
  .*        # 0 or more any character but newline
$           # end of line
```

**Screen capture:**

[image]